# php variable gets echoed twice

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a form when a function is called. My code is as follow :

```
function add_post(){
....
echo '<form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
      <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea>'
  .wp_dropdown_categories().'
    <input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/>
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
  ';
}
```

but `wp_dropdown_categories()` is displayed twice. Here is the HTML output:

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <!-- this should not be displayed -->
   <select class="postform" id="cat" name="cat">
    <option value="9" class="level-0">Entertainment</option>
   </select>
   <!-- form starts here -->
   <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input-title" size="45" name="post_title">
      <textarea id="text-desc" cols="66" name="post_content" rows="5"></textarea>
      <select class="postform" id="cat" name="cat">
        <option value="9" class="level-0">Entertainment</option>
      </select>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="new_post">
    <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="subput round">
   </form>
</div>
```

any idea why `wp_dropdown_categories()` is called twice?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `wp_dropdown_categories()` `echo`s the result. So you should either break your code in the following way:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
      <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea>
  ';
wp_dropdown_categories();
echo '<input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/>
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
  ';
```

or pass the `echo` variable to the function as zero as such:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
      <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea>'
  .wp_dropdown_categories('echo=0')).'
    <input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/>
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
  ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
See the documentation for this function [wp_dropdown_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

```
function add_post(){
....
echo '<form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
      <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea>'
  .wp_dropdown_categories(array('echo'=>0)).'
    <input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/>
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
  ';
}
```